# Axios call with axios.create and axios.get are not getting mocked

Tags: axios, jestjs

I have the following test file called controller.test.js. The actual code has an instance of axios with axios.create because I disabled the SSL verification.

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const axios = require('axios').create({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false // WARNING: This disables SSL verification.
    })
});
const logger = require('../../app/utils/logger'); // Assuming logger is in the utils folder.
```

I have mocked the httpsAgent and the axios create and get functions, I did this in another test and it worked, but it was an unit test, this one is a more complex test and it's giving issues. Everytime I call the function it's trying to call the actual axios instead of the mocked one.

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "https://proxmox.example.com/api2/json/nodes", Any<Object>

Number of calls: 0
```

The uncommented expect confirms that the function is not getting called. There's no problem with the inner function because I've tested it in unit tests and it works, the problem is 100% the mocking but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
// Mock the https module first
jest.mock('https', () => ({
    Agent: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    create: () => ({
        get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })), // Mock axios.get
    }),
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })), // Mock axios.get
}));

jest.mock('../../../config/configuration', () => ({
    loadServerConfig: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
            servers: [
                {
                    server: 'proxmox.example.com',
                    token_id: 'test-token-id',
                    secret: 'test-secret',
                },
            ],
        };
    }),
}));

// Mock the logger to avoid side effects
jest.mock('../../../app/utils/logger', () => ({
    info: jest.fn(),
    error: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('../../../app/services/proxmoxQueryService', () => ({
    getRRDData: jest.fn(),
}));

const axios = require('axios');
const { nodeAndVMFetchingController, fetchRRDData} = require('../../../app/controllers/controller');
const { loadServerConfig } = require("../../../config/configuration");
const { getRRDData } = require("../../../app/services/proxmoxQueryService");
const {error} = require("../../../app/utils/logger");
// Mock the configuration to provide a server list

describe('nodeAndVMFetchingController Integration Test', () => {
    const mockNodesResponse = { data: [
            {
                uptime: 1,
                id: 'nodeId',
                level: '',
                ssl_fingerprint: 'fingerprint',
                disk: 1,
                node: 'node',
                maxdisk: 1,
                mem: 1,
                maxmem: 1,
                cpu: 1,
                maxcpu: 1,
                type: 'node',
                status: 'online',
            }]};

    const mockVMsResponse =  { data: [
            {
                mem: 1,
                disk: 0,
                pid: 1,
                cpu: 1,
                uptime: 1,
                netin: 1,
                status: 'running',
                cpus: 0,
                diskread: 0,
                serial: 1,
                vmid: 1,
                name: 'name',
                maxmem: 1,
                netout: 1,
                diskwrite: 1,
                maxdisk: 1,
            },
    ]};

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Reset mocks before each test
        jest.resetAllMocks();

        // Re-mock loadServerConfig after resetting mocks
        loadServerConfig.mockReturnValue({
            servers: [
                {
                    server: 'proxmox.example.com',
                    token_id: 'test-token-id',
                    secret: 'test-secret',
                },
            ],
        });
    });


    it('successfully fetches nodes and VMs for each server', async () => {
        axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockNodesResponse)
        axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockVMsResponse)

        const result = await nodeAndVMFetchingController();

        // console.log("Servers: ", result)
        // console.log("Nodes: ", result[0].nodes)
        // console.log("VMs: ", result[0].nodes[0].vms)

        // Verify the expected structure of the result
        // expect(result).toEqual([
        //     {
        //         server: {
        //             server: 'proxmox.example.com',
        //             token_id: 'test-token-id',
        //             secret: 'test-secret',
        //         },
        //         nodes: [
        //             {
        //                 node: 'node',
        //                 vms: [
        //                     {
        //                         mem: 1,
        //                         disk: 0,
        //                         pid: 1,
        //                         cpu: 1,
        //                         uptime: 1,
        //                         netin: 1,
        //                         status: 'running',
        //                         cpus: 0,
        //                         diskread: 0,
        //                         serial: 1,
        //                         vmid: 1,
        //                         name: 'name',
        //                         maxmem: 1,
        //                         netout: 1,
        //                         diskwrite: 1,
        //                         maxdisk: 1,
        //                     },
        //                 ],
        //             },
        //         ],
        //     },
        // ]);

        // Verify axios.get was called with correct arguments for nodes
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            'https://proxmox.example.com/api2/json/nodes',
            expect.any(Object) // You can get more specific with the headers if needed
        );

        // // Verify axios.get was called with correct arguments for VMs
        // expect(mockAxiosGet).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        //     'https://proxmox.example.com/api2/json/nodes/node/qemu',
        //     expect.any(Object) // You can get more specific with the headers if needed
        // );
    });
});
```